# How can I view more of my history in Screen on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen, history

I was running scripts overnight from the command line (inside Screen on a Linux EC2 instance) and some errors that I was not tracking occurred.  I want to "scroll up" or view more of the history in Screen, but I cannot seem to find any commands that will work.

I need to see the onscreen output "further up" than I can on my current screen.  CTRL + a is supposed to put me into scroll mode inside Screen, but it's not working.

Comment: `history | less`, `more`? Or you are asking how to keep more history?

Comment: `history` will keep only commands have been fired in shell. He is more asking about logging sort of stuff

Comment: `<Shift>` + `<PgUp>` is the only option. And it has some limit as well (at most last 500 lines, I guess).

Comment: I need to see the onscreen output "further up" than I can on my current screen.  CTRL + a is supposed to put me into scroll mode inside Screen, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Just `Ctrl-a` is `screen`'s escape. The whole key sequence to enter scrollback mode would be `Ctrl-a` `[`, as opyate says. `Ctrl-a` `ESC` also works for me, I don't remember which one is standard / commonly used.

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760346/how-do-i-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-in-a-running-screen-session

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you start screen you can specify the size of the scrollback buffer with -h, so you can increase it from the default of 100 lines.   However, with a currently running screen, once the data has left the buffer, it is gone.

[edit for clarity]
@opyate explains how to use the scroll back buffer in his answer. I copy that answer here as it give more clarity and improves this answer for newcomers.

> Assuming you haven't overriden your escape sequence, you can press
> `Ctrl-a [` to go into scrollback mode, then use the usual
> `Page-UP/Page-DOWN` or `Ctrl-b/Ctrl-f` to go up and down.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. The answer by @opyate does provide a solution

Comment: @nirvana-msu  Using ^a to enter scrollback mode allows you to page up the scrollback buffer.  If data is already gone from the scrollback buffer, it is gone.  You can increase the size of that bufer at startup.  What exactly about my answer do you think is incorrect?  I talk about increasing the size of the scrollback buffer, opyate gives details on how to use it.

Comment: Well, ok, though the question wasn't really about extending scroll buffer. The author wanted to view more history than what's normally shown in console, and you _can_ view more history using `Ctrl+a+[`. Your answer just makes it seem like it's not possible, which is misleading.

Comment: This is not working on a mac. The other answers are not working neither.

Answer (score 116):

Assuming you haven't overriden your escape sequence, you can press `Ctrl-a [` to go into scrollback mode, then use the usual Page-UP/Page-DOWN or Ctrl-b/Ctrl-f to go up and down.

From [the Gentoo wiki on Screen usage](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Screen#Copy.2C_paste.2C_and_scroll_operations)

Comment: and ESC to exit scrollback mode, IIRC

Comment: now the gentoo wiki is: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Screen

Comment: also see [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/310251/use-terminal-scrollbar-with-tmux/314620#314620) for how to (sort of) get scrolling with the mouse working.  The post name says its for tmux but it also covers screen

Comment: `Ctrl`+`A`,`Esc` also enters the copy/scrollback mode.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you this answer and the comment by @SergeStroobandt saved me 10 hours of work.

Comment: `Ctrl + A`, `Esc` should be the easiest way (for memorize) to scroll back.

Answer (score 21):

> I need to see the onscreen output "further up" than I can on my current screen. CTRL + a is supposed to put me into scroll mode inside Screen, but it's not working.

In complement to the other answers, I would point out that you may add in your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
defscrollback 100000
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
```

where:

- `defscrollback 100000`: set the default number of scrollback lines to `100000`
- `termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@`: allow terminal scrolling in either xterm or PuTTY. ([screen FAQ](http://www4.cs.fau.de/~jnweiger/screen-faq.html); [PuTTY FAQ](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-screen))

Comment: Not working on a Mac. None of the answers work here. I still can just see the size of the Terminal window. Further up is just the `screen` command and the stuff I did before screen. I also tried `screen -h`, same result. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ben sorry no idea, I only tried on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, it does work with `control` + `a` and then `ESC` and then I am able to scroll inside the text with the cursor. What does not work is scrolling with the mouse using the Mac Terminal sliders on the side. Thanks!

Comment: Bomben's answer make this more accurate in termcapinfo line add '\*' after xterm.
That is `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@`

you may find (as I did on Ubuntu) that my terminal type is `xterm-256color`
And terminal inside of screen is of type `screen.xterm-256color`. So perhaps even use `*xterm*` to ensure nesting of screens works.

Comment: Oh sweet, thanks for that termcapinfo!

Answer (score 9):

You can also change the scrollback history size in a running screen with the sequence `CTRL-a` `:` (enter screen command-line mode), then `scrollback 10000` if you want 10k lines of history buffer. The change applies immediately.

Be careful of memory usage if you use many screens with very long buffers.

However, like @William Pursell said, with a currently running screen, once the data has left the buffer, it is gone.

Answer (score 7):

You can also run your commands in the `script` command which will log the output to disk.  Or you can:  `command 2>&1 | tee /tmp/cmd.out` to log the output for future investigation in you wanted a (practically) infinite sized output history.

Comment: this is what I ended up using for my task.  Works great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a **macOS Terminal** I was not able to use the sliders at the side to see text history.

I was able to scroll with the cursor inside the text using <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>  after I hit <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

And I had to add this to `~/.screenrc` to enable mouse scrolling from inside the window (still not with the sliders):

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what terminal program you are using, you can usually change the Scrolling Buffer under Settings. I know for `xterm` you have to enable Scrolling first, then you can set the buffer to infinite.

Your best bet however for logging scripts would be to Re-direct the standard output to a file:

```
ScriptName >> OutputFile.txt
```

Doing it this way you can scroll and search freely as well as keep a record (i.e. in case your computer crashes).

EDIT: This is close to the piping solution above, however redirecting standard input can be useful in other instances as well:

```
grep linux stackoverflow.txt > linuxquestions.txt
```

or

```
cat linuxquestions.txt | grep buffersize > bufferquestions.txt
```

Comment: Do note that `screen(1)` doesn't _allow_ terminal scrolling. That's both one of its main features and one of its main drawbacks.

Comment: @sarnold It's possible to allow terminal scrolling, see https://superuser.com/a/1336554/116475

Answer (score 0):

#### <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>

also enters the copy/scrollback mode of `screen`.